# Rounded corners not working in IE (.rounded-corners)

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer, rounded-corners

I am trying to get rounded corners in IE pn the following website using the border-radius.htc ( http://www.htmlremix.com/css/curved-corner-border-radius-cross-browser ) method but it doesn't seem to be working.

When you hover over the menu the level 2 sub menu should have round corners but doesn't (IE8).

Search the HTML source for .rounded-corners to see where it is applied and should be showing but isn't.

Can anyone please help?

http://berrisford.gumpshen.com

```
.ie6 .rounded-corners, .ie7 .rounded-corners, .ie8 .rounded-corners, .ie9 .rounded-corners {
  behavior: url(border-radius.htc);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can't you just use:

```
.ie6 .rounded-corners, .ie7 .rounded-corners, .ie8 .rounded-corners, .ie9 .rounded-corners {
  behavior: url(border-radius.htc);
  border-radius: 4px; /* example */
}
```

It also assures that it tries also the CSS way of rounding the corner.

Comment: Tried that it doesn't work for some reason, can you think of anything else?

Comment: It works fine for me in IE, FireFox, Chrome. IE 7,8,9 make sure you hard-refresh it could be your CSS cached usually CTRL+R for IE